# How is after market tradings inserted in stock market graphs?

Tags: stock-market

When I open a stock market graph tool such as Metastock and enter in the intra-day periodicities, I can never found the data related to the after market operations. I know (by observation) that when the market is in the initial moments just before being closed, all the operations are put inside the last candles (so e.g. if the market closes at 5 pm, the after-market operations between 5pm and 5:15 pm are all inserted in the candle related to 4:50-5:00 pm in the 10 minute graph).

But what about all the moves done after that? Are all after market operations inserted as part of the last candle?

Comment: In what sense "the market has closed", if operations continue long after the official closing hour?

Comment: @There is the official opening and official closing of the market, but after that there is the "after-market" when some operations are still done and change the price of the stock - by whom they are done? I have no idea, but I know they exist. :)